# How do I write a converter to change a PHP file into a Bash file?

Tags: php, filenames

My so far not-so-bad version to implement this is:

```
function bashFileConvert($file)
{
    return preg_replace('/([^\/\s]+\s+[^\/]+)(\/|$)/','"${1}"${2}',$file);
}
```

which mostly processes the problem when there is a space in the file name,like

```
$flie = '/usr/local/my test file.txt'
```

while will not be recognizable for Bash.

So I need to convert to

```
$file = '/usr/local/"my test file.txt"'
```

before calling something like:

```
exec('ls ' . $file);
```

But there are still many other corner cases, like the quote and '&' problem.

So, is there a ready version to do this job?

==================================

Now I tried escapeshellarg(), but it is a little strange here:

```
$file = '/usr/local/apache2/resumes_txt/5/San Francisco/qtzhang/Device "Engineer"/Job Resume Qintao Zhang.pdf.txt';
echo escapeshellarg($file);

D:\\test>php test.php
"/usr/local/apache2/resumes_txt/5/San Francisco/qtzhang/Device  Engineer /Job Resume Qintao Zhang.pdf.txt"
```

It seems with this function, a quote is replaced with a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use the escapeshellarg function in PHP (http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php):

```
$file = escapeshellarg('/usr/local/my test file.txt');

exec('ls ' . $file);
```

It will wrap quotes round it and escape quotes for you.

Comment: What if there is a " in file itself?

Comment: Seems " is replaced with a space by this function?I've updated my post

Comment: You are running windows here - windows does not allow double quotes in filenames, that is probably why escapeshellarg replaces them with spaces.  Linux has no such limitation, so the quotes remain (I have tested this).